# How to increase card count in greenhopper display?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

I want to see more items in the list view for greenhopper.  With epics, stories, etc (and not being able to collapse the stories into the epics) there's a lot of items to be arranging.  I can't seem to drag between pages, so I want to see more items on a page.  I can't find a way to set that up.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the wrench icon (tools) -> User preferences and set on each separator Issues / Page field. Default is 30.